# How to enforce GSI uniqueness on a PutItemRequest

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to use a `PutItemRequest` to insert records into a DynamoDB table, however I do not want the insert to succeed when certain values on the inserted item already exist on other items.

Here is the code for the request:

```
var req = PutItemRequest.builder()
            .tableName(TABLE_NAME)
            .item(getAllValues(settings))
            .conditionExpression("attribute_not_exists(#" + MAC_ADDRESS + ") AND attribute_not_exists(#" + REGISTRATION_CODE + ")")
            .expressionAttributeNames(Map.of("#" + MAC_ADDRESS, MAC_ADDRESS, "#" + REGISTRATION_CODE, REGISTRATION_CODE))
            .build();
```

The table already contains an item with a mac address of '000000000000' so I would expect the above to fail when trying to insert another item with the same mac address, but the insert succeeds.

What am I doing wrong here? Both MAC_ADDRESS and REGISTRATION_CODE are GSI's.

Comment: How can an attribute be a GSI, that makes no sense? Is the mac address the partition key? Is there a sort key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make this possible introduces a lot of overhead which perhaps is not the best solution for your use-case.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/

I would suggest that you rethink your tables schema to allow the base table handle the uniqueness and have the indexes based on other attributes.

Comment: Seems like we are using dynamodb when we shouldn't - switched to another, less temperamental db engine.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the actual DDB table, GSI's and LSI's always allow duplicates.

What are you using as a primary key (hash & sort) for the table itself?

If you want to DDB enforce uniqueness, you'll need to come up with a way to use the unique attributes in the table's primary key.